# How to close browser entirely using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, safari, mozilla

I want to close my full browser using JavaScript.

I used

```
window.close()
```

and also

```
self.close()
```

and also

```
 var win = window.open('', '_self');
 window.close();
 win.close();
```

and also

```
var win = window.open('', '_parent');
win.close();
```

None of these give me any benefit in this regard.

Is there anything else in JavaScript which will help me to close my browser instead of only a tab and also will work in all browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to let you know, you can only close windows with Javascript that were opened by it

Comment: thanks for the info .Is there anything to override it ?

Comment: There isn't anything to override it. If there were anything, that would be potentially harmful

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi No and thank god there isn't. Think of the bad impact this could have.